# Ubuntu 17.10 Network Printer Does Not Accept Jobs

Tags: networking, server, printing, cups-lpd

I have an HP printer connected by USB to my desktop computer running Ubuntu 17.10.  I can print from any application on that desktop to the printer. When I look at the printer details it indicates that the printer is shared.

I try to print from my laptop running 17.10 which is connected by WiFi to the router into which the desktop is plugged.  The network printer appears when I try to print from an application as attached through a host name defined in my hosts file.  I can connect to the desktop computer using FTP and other functions such as ping.  The printer appears with status "Printer does not accept jobs".

[image: Printer Status Image]

The CUPS log is:

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/cups/access_log
[sudo] password for jcobban: 
localhost - - [26/Mar/2018:02:29:25 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-Subscription client-error-not-found
localhost - root [26/Mar/2018:03:14:00 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 187 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [26/Mar/2018:19:33:28 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27086 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [26/Mar/2018:19:33:28 -0400] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 211 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer client-error-bad-request
localhost - - [26/Mar/2018:19:40:44 -0400] "POST /printers/HP_Deskjet_F4500_series_jcobban_server HTTP/1.1" 200 102781 Print-Job successful-ok
```

I do not understand what is going wrong or how to get the document to print.

Comment: check if there is any conflict in IP addresses.